# UML/RUP and non OO applications

Tags: design-patterns, uml

At my current job, we are currently implementing UML and RUP for the day by day coding and designing...

The current structure have 2% of all code (100000+ lines) object oriented... So they have this issue, when a developer have this new "case" (ir, requirement, etc) they must complete all the documentation and analysis to that old thing...

They must write the stakeholder request, uses cases identification, uses cases in detail, use case diagram, class diagram and sequence diagram...

As I see it, it's very difficult to implement a uml/rup architecture to the existing non-oo applications..

My question is, is this a common scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  This is a common scenario.  Folks use RUP to design Relational Databases, which are about as far from OO programming as you can get.

Don't confuse OO analysis,  project management and non-OO programming.

This is normal.

> They must write the stakeholder request, uses cases identification, uses cases in detail, use case diagram, class diagram and sequence diagram...

Correct.  You must **always** do this.  RUP or Scrum or Waterfall or Whatever-Methodology-you-choose.  You **must** do this.  No use cases == Epic Fail.  No Stakeholder == Epic Fail. These are not OO concepts.  These are just Plain Old Common Sense.

> As I see it, it's very difficult to implement a uml/rup architecture to the existing non-oo applications..

Why?  RUP works fine for non-OO.